# Magento adding zend component

Tags: magento, zend-framework

I have magento web site. I need to integrate the Google Analytics API, and I found this component: https://github.com/danielmitd/Zend_Gdata_Analytics

I see that Zend_Gdata already included in magento, but which is the proper way (upgrade safe) to add the above component to magento?

I suppose placing it to the magento/lib/Zend/ directory is not upgrade safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento upgrades are just file overwriting, so any Zend component which you would like to upgrade or add can be done under *`lib/Zend/`* if it will not be replaced by a subsequent upgrade (note that Magento releases are pegged to specific versions of ZF1).

That said, it's possible to provide the specific Zend component version you need under *`app/code/local/Zend/`* because of `include_path` bootstrapping, and this will work fine.